# Enable Buttons when Animation finished android

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have a `ViewFlipper` with 3 views each one display a different Layout , each child have a next button.

when clicked it animated the transition to the other child using "ViewFlipper" . What i want when the user click a button an animation starts i want to disable all button to prevent Animation collision .
what i faced when i click multiple time very fast on a button i restart the animation over .

what i have tried so far

now by connection all animtion object to one Listener and 
keep a boolean falg to indicate if an animation is running or not . and in the `onTouchEvent()` of the `Activity` if the flag is true i return true else i return the super method.
this flag set to true in the `onAnimationStart` callback and set to false in `onAnimationEnd` didnt work.
and when i log the method calls it shows that `onAnimationEnd` called before the animation ends completely.

Any suggestion  to solve this problem ??

code

```
public class CreateNewKhtmehActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnClickListener, AnimationListener {    
    AtomicBoolean isAnimationPlaying = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    // phase 1
    Button phase1_continue_button;
    // phase 2      
    Button phase2_continue_button;
    // phase 3
    Button phase3_start_session;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ViewFlipper flipper;
    Animation flip_in_from_left, flip_in_from_right, flip_out_to_left,
            flip_out_to_right, stay_still;

    RelativeLayout phase1;
    RelativeLayout phase2;
    RelativeLayout phase3;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.create_new_session);

        /*
         * 
         * phase 1
         */
        phase1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.phase1);
        setUpUIForPhase1(phase1);

        // phase2
        phase2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.phase2);
        setUpUIForPhase2(phase2);

        // phase 3
        phase3 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.phase3);
        setUpUIForPhase3(phase3);
        /*
         * Animation
         */

        flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.main_flipper);
        flipper.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        flipper.setDisplayedChild(2);
        flip_in_from_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                getApplicationContext(), R.anim.push_in_from_left);
        flip_in_from_left.setAnimationListener(this);
        flip_in_from_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                getApplicationContext(), R.anim.push_in_from_right);
        flip_in_from_right.setAnimationListener(this);
        flip_out_to_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                getApplicationContext(), R.anim.push_out_to_left);
        flip_out_to_left.setAnimationListener(this);
        flip_out_to_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                getApplicationContext(), R.anim.push_out_to_right);
        flip_out_to_right.setAnimationListener(this);
        stay_still = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.stay_still);

        stay_still.setAnimationListener(this);


    }

    private void setUpUIForPhase3(View v) {

        phase3_start_session = (Button) v
                .findViewById(R.id.start_session_button);
        phase3_start_session.setOnClickListener(this);
     }


    private void setUpUIForPhase2(View v) {

        phase2_continue_button = (Button) v
                .findViewById(R.id.phase2_continue_button);
        phase2_continue_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void setUpUIForPhase1(View v) {
        phase1_continue_button = (Button) phase1
                .findViewById(R.id.phase1_continue_Button);
        phase1_continue_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onBackPressed() {

        int currentChild = flipper.getDisplayedChild();
        switch (currentChild) {
        // first displayed child
        case 0:
            flipNext();
            if (this.move_from_phase1_to_phase3) {
                flipper.setDisplayedChild(2);

            } else {
                spinner_from.invalidate();
                spinner_to.invalidate();
                flipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
            }

            break;
        case 1:
            flipNext();
            flipper.setDisplayedChild(2);
            break;
        default:
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("onClick");

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.phase1_continue_Button:
            spinner_from.invalidate();
            spinner_to.invalidate();
            flipPrevious();
            if (this.move_from_phase1_to_phase3) {
                flipper.setDisplayedChild(0);
            } else {
                flipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
            }

            break;
        case R.id.phase2_continue_button:
            flipPrevious();
            flipper.setDisplayedChild(0);

            break;

        case R.id.start_session_button:
            insetNewSession();

            break;

        }

    }

    // Methods concerning the flip

    public void flipNext() {

        flipper.setInAnimation(flip_in_from_right);

        flipper.setOutAnimation(flip_out_to_left);

    }

    public void flipPrevious() {

        flipper.setInAnimation(flip_in_from_left);

        flipper.setOutAnimation(flip_out_to_right);

    }

    public void stayStill() {

        flipper.setInAnimation(stay_still);

        flipper.setOutAnimation(stay_still);

    }

     .......
     ........

     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     System.out.println("isAnimationPlaying " + isAnimationPlaying.get());
     if (isAnimationPlaying.get()) {
     return true;
     } else {
     return super.onTouchEvent(event);
     }

    // }

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        System.out.println("onAnimationEnd");
            isAnimationPlaying.set(true);
    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        System.out.println("onAnimationRepeat");
    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        System.out.println("onAnimationStart");
        isAnimationPlaying.set(false);

    }

}
```

Comment: can you post yoru animating code?

Comment: I am not sure why it wouldn't work as is, but Arhimed's answer should do the trick. Also side note (unrelated to your issue) you should use `CreateNewKhtmehActivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()` That method is unnecessary here and prone to memory leaks.

Comment: AFAIK the Activity context can cause memory leak what cases should ApplicationContext leaks memory , can you provide me with a link or an article for that?

Comment: In this case you just call a static util method that uses a `Context` instance just to load a resource. It does not keep a reference on the passed in `Context` instance. Since all this happens on the main UI thread inside of `onCreate` it is safe to use an instance of the `Activity` here.

Comment: @Nammari [see this answer by CommonsWare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context/7298955#7298955) Which also links to another answer given by Ms. Hackborn of the Android dev team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest 2 improvements (however I had no chance to try it with `ViewFlipper` so I can't guarantee it will do the desired trick):

**1)** Set the flag to `true` even before animation starts (let it be the first thing to do inside of the button click listener).

**2)** In attempt to extend the time the flag is true, don't set it to `false` inside of the `onAnimationEnd`. Instead of direct setting let the `onAnimationEnd` to create a `Runnable` (that would set the flag to `false`) and post it to be run the next time UI thread is ready to do it. So instead of setting it right now, it will be done **later** (once the current UI thread working units have been run). Just in case you don't know - internally there is a message queue of Runnables to be executed on the main UI thread. And `onAnimationEnd` is run on the main UI thread as a part of the current UI changes. Once the UI changes are done your `Runnable` will be processed. This way you postpone setting to false. It should be smth like this:

```
@Override
protected void onAnimationEnd() {
    Runnable resetter = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            yourFlag = false;
        }
    };
    // handler is an instance of android.os.Handler,
    // it should be created somewhere before on the main UI thread
    // using the simplest Handler() constructor
    handler.post(resetter);
}
```

Comment: note: if you need to squeek out even more time you can use `handler.post(resetter,100);` where `100` is a millisecond value that will delay the runnable by that many milliseconds. So in this case it would delay it by an extra 1/10 of a second, play with the value until it is where you want it.

Comment: please see the UPDATE section

Comment: @Arhimed i used your trick with one listener for all Animation since one animation can run at a time no overlapping . anyway could you tell me why should i create new animation each time i need need them ??? what is the hidden story behind that?!

Comment: Actually I decided to be top careful just from a quick glance on your code (there was not a deep analysis). If you are sure animations don't overlap, then it should be Ok as is.

Comment: I removed the UPDATE section because it appeared to be irrelevant. Sorry for this mess.